# How to plot a bar and line on the same chart with separate axes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot bars and a line on different y axes on the same chart using matplotlib. They don't appear on the same chart for some reason, the following code works in certain situations but it doesn't in this case.

```
d = {'Flag': [0.2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5],
     'Year': [1956, 1994, 1994, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2019]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

bin_grp = df.groupby(df.Year)
grp = bin_grp['Flag'].agg(['mean', 'count'])

plt.figure()
ax1 = grp['count'].plot(color='green', kind='bar')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
grp['mean'].plot(ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

From working with slightly different data in this same situation, my gut feel is that the issue is arising from bar chart treating the x axis as non-numeric while the line chart is treating it as numeric, then the 'gaps' in the x axis values are causing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, this should be related to the x-axis. An [old github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4387) mentions a similar problem where setting `sharex=False` solves the issue. I couldn't find any more precise information than that on why this issue appears.

However, to get the correct plot in this case, you can use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot` function instead of `pandas.DataFrame.plot` as follows.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.bar(grp.index, grp['count'], color='green')
ax2.plot(grp.index, grp['mean'])
plt.show()
```